# Android TUN interface not working inside Linux-Deploy chroot. Up but no any packets

Tags: android, linux-kernel, openvpn, chroot, tun

I am trying to bring up openvpn client on Android 5.0 inside linux-deploy chroot with Debian Buster inside (android kernel 3.10.65)

The tun is up and get ip address, but no any packets transfered. No ping works or any tcp connection. Openvpn successfully keep-alives and didn't drop, stays connected forever. The same config works on my pc. 
It is not openvpn related. I tried to bring up tun with socat

Socat TUN is also not working
http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-tun.html

socat -d -d -d TCP:10.0.9.77:11443 TUN:192.168.255.2/24,up

```
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] I socat by Gerhard Rieger and contributors - see www.dest-unreach.org
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] I This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit. (http://www.openssl.org/)
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] I This product includes software written by Tim Hudson (tjh@cryptsoft.com)
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] N opening connection to AF=2 10.0.9.77:11443
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] I starting connect loop
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] I socket(2, 1, 6) -> 5
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 10.0.9.95:52792
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] I setting option "iff-up" to 1
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] N creating tunnel network interface
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] I open("/dev/net/tun", 02, 0666) -> 6
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] I socket(2, 2, 0) -> 7
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] I resolved and opened all sock addresses
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [6,6]
2019/10/31 20:32:01 socat[29853] N socket 1 (fd 5) is at EOF
2019/10/31 20:32:02 socat[29853] I poll timed out (no data within 0.500000 seconds)
2019/10/31 20:32:02 socat[29853] I shutdown(5, 2)
2019/10/31 20:32:02 socat[29853] N exiting with status 0
```

The firewall is totally clean:

```
iptables-legacy -X
iptables-legacy -t raw -X
iptables-legacy -t nat -X
iptables-legacy -t mangle -X
iptables-legacy -t raw -F
iptables-legacy -t nat -F
iptables-legacy -t mangle -F
iptables-legacy -F
```

If I run socat-server on android, and my computer as client - both tun0 up, but no ping.

I found on google about android: Only NET_ADMIN is allowed to fully control TUN interfaces

What is means? Maybe CONFIG_PARANOID_NETWORK causes problems?

I tried to usermod -a -G 300{1,2,3,4,5} root
but it not helped.

Please help to get packets inside tun interface.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

ip rule add from all lookup main pref 1